# async task timer

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

I have an app which use AsyncTask to call an web service and parse an xml,I want to know the duration between the moment when it starts and the moment when it finishes,I am doing like this but every time the var difftime is 0;

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    completed=false;
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
  //code 
 }

  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        difftime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
  }
```

Comment: Is `onPostExecute()` actually called?

Comment: try using System.nanoTime()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work. I executed your code as following, it works :

```
private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {
    private long time;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("TestTask", "difftime = "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }
}
```

Check the signature of your AsyncTask :

```
extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean>
```

Comment: +1 thats what I was about to post here @gezdy you made it 2 seconds fast.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long time;
long difftime;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    completed=false;
    time = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
  //code 
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    difftime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try System.nanoTime() instead. That's how you get hi-resolution timers in Android.

There are some notorious pitfalls with this API call on some platforms. e.g. on Windows you can't use System.nanoTime() results across different threads. The same issue would probably apply for any multi-core x86 processor runnning Android, I would think.

If you're just using it for benchmarking, that's probably a reasonable choice. If you're expecting it to run consistently in the field on 2300 different android devices, that's probably a very bad idea. Even uptimeMillis() has spectacularly bizarre behaviour (running at quarter-speed, for example) on some mainstream Android 2.x power-managed devices. I've seen it myself.

I have to admit, I'm curious as to how well that API does work across Android devices, in terms of accuracy, precision, and minimum increment. I dont' really know.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you need to get the system.currentTimeMillis inside doInBackground().

Like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    completed=false;
}
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
      final long START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
      // Code 
 }

  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        final long DIFF_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis() - START_TIME;
  }
```

Also make sure that you're declaring the times as longs. They are long. :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does it have to change anymore?

Comment: There is an other problem in your code. `doBackground` and `onPostExecute` are executed not in the same task. So in this case, you should declare startTime volatile.

Comment: if you put `private volatile long startTime` as AsyncTask member, it should work